# Explicit Example of a Smooth Complete Intersection

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am seeking explicit examples of projective smooth complete intersections in any projective space.

For example, in $\mathbb{P}^5$, I can find intersections of cubics and quadrics which are smooth complete intersections, but I have been unable to write down an explicit set of equations so that the intersection passes through the point $p=[1:0:0:\dots:0]$.

My main question is: Is there a method by which one can generate many examples of such projective varieties? Using moduli counts, one should be able to find them (and there are results saying that they do exist). Looking through the Macaualy2 documentation, there does not seem to be a known method. On the other hand, one could theoretically write a program that computes lots of ideals and uses the "isCI()" and isSmooth()" functions of Macaulay2 to find examples. For the moment, all I really want examples that satisfy three conditions

(a) it passes through $[1:0:0:\dots:0]$,

(b) the complete intersection is smooth in $\mathbb{P}^n$,

(c) the variety is sufficiently nice i.e. the complete intersection is Fano,

(d) the variety is not "degenerate" i.e. it does not sit in a smaller projective space.

How might one cook up such an example without suffering from computational issues?

Comment: For a hypersurface of degree $d$ the condition that it pass through $[1:0:\cdots:0]$ is just that the coefficient of $X_0^d$ in the defining equation should equal $0$. If you choose polynomials "at random" subject to this condition, you will satisfy (a), (b), and (d). If one of your hypersurfaces is a quadric you can be more concrete,since all smooth quadrics of a given dimension are the same up to change of coordinates: you can take the quadric to be given e..g. by $X_0X_1 + X_2^2 + \cdots X_5^2$, and then choose the cubic "at random" among those cubics with no $X_0^3$ term.

Comment: @LazzaroCampeotti That is a nice way to do that case. I am unfortunately not very good at programming in Macaulay2 as of yet. Is there a general approach to reducing the computation complexity of say three intersections of larger degrees? For the Fano condition, it is just a condition on degrees so I’m hppy there.

Comment: Your conditions imply that the variety in question must be a threefold or fourfold. Fourfold is a hypersurface of degree at most five. If it is a threefold, then it is a complete intersection of type $(2,2)$ or $(2,3)$. Computationally making it pass through a point  can not be difficult since it is just a linear change of coordinates, once you have some point in the intersection.

Comment: @Mohan, I realized that my question was phrased rather poorly. I would like to not restrict to the situation of $\mathbb{P}^5$ but in any arbitrary projective space. The example of $\mathbb{P}^5$ was because it is the simplest case where things get interesting.